# What is this form of integral equation called and what are the classes of solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

This is probably a quick one for someone familiar with integral equations:

I have an equation of the form $\int_{a}^{b}du \, g(u,v) \, f(u)=c$ with $a$, $b$, and $c$ constant; and $f(u)$ a known function (with $g(u,v)$ unknown).

Since this is a simple form it seems that someone at some point probably studied it extensively, but I can't find any info on it by searching because I don't know what it would be called. It looks like the "reverse" case, with the unknown function being of a single variable and the known being of two, is fairly well known (Fredholm equation).

Many thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation ?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Hey, thanks for the comment, but the wiki says that for the Volterra equation it is the **unknown** function which has one variable and the known one which has two. Do you know what the opposite is called?

Comment: Oh, I see. That's difficult... surely $c$ would be at least a function of $v$?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Actually no, not in my case. In fact it is this property of "marginal flatness" that I am hoping places some constraints on a particular physical system I am studying. To be exact the function $g$ is actually some unknown probability measure I want to try to find some constraints for.

Comment: Have you considered that $\displaystyle g(u,v) = \frac{c}{f(u)(b-a)}$ is a solution?

Comment: It looks like there are probably infinite solutions - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102250/fredholm-integrals-of-the-second-kind-with-an-unknown-kernel

Comment: @BennettGardiner Okay cool, the link is potentially helpful. Somewhat unrelated: what's the difference between Mathematics and MathOverflow? Is the latter exclusive to professional mathematicians?

Comment: It's not exclusive but it does seem more geared towards research. Some big names occasionally contribute.